# how to display documents firestoredatabase in home screen flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I want to display the documents in Firestore database in home screen by using snapshot

**I need something like this**

```
Text('documents["name"]')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
List<String> _groupsId = [];

await fireStore
    .collection('groups')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
    _groupsId.add(doc.id);
  }
});
```

You will get all list key of documents